# How to get promises to work in IE10 with react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, es6-promise

I am trying to fetch data using promise in my react application. I installed and implemented this polyfill [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) but works for IE11 on window 8 but IE10 window 7 is says 'promise are undefined'. I assumed the polyfill is meant to cover all IE9+, but it is just not working for me. Has anyone come across this problem? Am I missing something in the implementation of the es6-promise polyfill with webpack??

```
// calling it my jsx file

    import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
    import es6promise from 'es6-promise'; // not sure if I need this in the jsx file also??
    promise.polyfill();
    import 'isomorphic-fetch';
    class App extends React.Component {
      ...
    }
    App.propTypes = propTypes;

    export default App;

webpack.config.js
var promise = require('es6-promise').polyfill();
switch (TARGET) {
    case 'build':
        module.exports = mergeConfig({
            plugins: [
                // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
                // Minify all javascript. Loaders are switched into minimizing mode
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                    compress: {
                        warnings: false
                    }
                }),
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    'process.env': {
                        // This has effect on the react lib size
                        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
                    }
                }),
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    PROMISE: promise
                })
            ]
        });

        break;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `es6promise.polyfill` if you import `es6-promise` as `es6promise`?

Comment: ok, do mean that if I am requiring it in the webpack, I should not then import it in my jsx?
Have since remove the import from the jsx page I am fetching the data but getting error. I really want to know a standard why of getting the polyfill to work with webpack so it fixes IE10

Answer (score 1):

You can try babel-polyfill.
After install it as dependency.
Import it in your app.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an another interesting solution (it works for me in that case). I didn't want to import a polyfill into every file so I provided via WebpackProvidePlugin.

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

        "Promise": "babel-polyfill",
        'fetch': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader? 
                  global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    })
```

So now I can use these stuff without importing into every file. And a very important note. Some resources are suggesting to use  **es6-promise** instead **babel-polyfill**, I tried to use it but it doesn't work for me. Looks like es6-promise-polyfill didn't work in case of using webpack + babel. So I switched to the *babel-polyfill*. Tested in the IE11 and all is fine.

Hope it helps.

Best Regard. Velidan.

Comment: You can put babel-polyfill as the first item of `entry` in your Webpack config, like in `entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/App.js']`, and this line alone does the trick. No need to do `webpack.ProvidePlugin`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but in that case I had a some interesting issue in IE11: 
`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `RedBoxError` . 
 It was happened because the polyfill should be loaded after React-DOM and React, actually I changed the order but it wasn't working somehow so I used ProvidePlugin.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `native-promise-polyfill` [npm module](https://github.com/getify/native-promise-only), especially if you don't need the other features [babel-polyfill includes](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/):

> This means you can use new built-ins like Promise or WeakMap, static methods like Array.from or Object.assign, instance methods like Array.prototype.includes, and generator functions

Comment: whats the difference in using this polyfill in comparison to using es6-polyfill?

Comment: es6-polyfill should probably works fine as well, the difference is that native-promise-polyfill aims to stick as close to the Promise spec as possible, and is ~7kb compared to es6-polyfills ~27kb.